# Windows subsystem for Linux upgrade error

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows 11, and I want to use WSL2. Now I have WSL and I could not upgrade it to the WSL2. I followed the Microsoft WSL2 upgrade documentation  page for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual but they do not help. Whenever type the wsl related commands what I see is the following image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjnRN.png). I am changing the wsl with wsl.exe but the problem still occurs. I also followed the possible solutions related to Windows update installations, but they did not help me. Here is how I my Windows installations look like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWeQX.png)

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 from Microsoft Store. When I type `wsl --status`  to the powershell, what I see is Default Distribution: Ubuntu and Default Version: 1

I have also watched several videos how to convert wsl to wsl2 but, none of them suggests solution for the error I provide in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjnRN.png)

Comment: WSL is part of Windows, not part of Ubuntu. You need to raise the question in a forum focusing on support for Windows.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#uninstall-legacy-version-of-wsl to uninstall WSL1, then you can install WSL2.

Comment: The question is not Ubuntu related, it is about Win.